# how to navigation when onpress inside an alert

Tags: react-native, navigation, alert

i trying to make a navigation to another screen when press a button on alert but i keep getting erro " [Error: TransformError SyntaxError: D:\one\HomeScreen.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (63:82) "
below is my code
please help me thank you guys
*some random words so i can post this question*

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        input: {
          username: null,
          email: null,
          password: null,
          confirm_password: null,
        },
        errors: {
          username: null,
          email: null,
          password: null,
          confirm_password: null,
        },
      };
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
      //event.preventDefault();
    
      if (this.validate()) {
        alert('ok');
        console.log(this.state);
    
         this.setState((prevState) => {
                let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
                input.username = null;
                input.password = null;
                input.email = null;
                input.confirm_password = null;
                return { input };
         });
           this.setState((prevState) => {
                let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
                errors.username = null;
                errors.password = null;
                errors.email = null;
                errors.confirm_password = null;
                return { errors };
         });
    
         Alert.alert('Đã Đăng Ký',
         'Xin Hãy Đăng Nhập',
         [
          {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style={styles.container}},
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('List'), //code to navigate}
         ],
         { cancelable: false });
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: @Konstantin  [Error: TransformError SyntaxError: D:\one\HomeScreen.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (63:82) it like that

Answer (score 0):

Nvm i did it just remove one ","  here is code in alert

```
Alert.alert('Đã Đăng Ký',
     'Xin Hãy Đăng Nhập',
     [
      {text: 'Thoat', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed')},
      // {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('List'), //code to navigate}
      {text: 'Tien Len', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('List')}
     ],
     { cancelable: false });
```